# Combine two result from CryptoJS

Tags: node.js, express, cryptography, cryptojs

I have used AES encryption with CryptoJS library on the Nodejs and everything works fine
But finally I want to put the IV in first 16 byte then encrypted data into an array byte then base64 it But I don't know how to do it in nodejs

```
let secret = 'Hello';
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('QVNES0FVemFzZHVoMjM0MzIyNjlCNTIyRTcwNUQ0RjI='); 
let ivByte= crypto.randomBytes(16);
let newIV= this.toCryptoJSWordArray(ivByte);
```

I will encrypt like this :

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(secret, key, {iv: newIV, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
```

Every this is fine and result is :

```
 console.log({
            text:'Hello',
            iv:CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(newIV), 
            enc:CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(e1.ciphertext), 
        })
```

Both output IV & encrypted text base64 correctly and as I expected

Now I want to combine these two into an array bytes (Like first 16byte is IV + encrypted data (None are base64) and then convert them to base64 format,
meaning u before base64 IV and Encrypted text combine them to one array then base64 them but I don't know how do it
Expected output is :
QVNES0FVemFzZHVoMjM0MzIyNjlCNTIyRTcwNUQ0RjI=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CryptoJS provides [`concat()`](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/core.js#L277) for the concatenation of WordArrays: `wa1.concat(wa2)`. This appends `wa2` to `wa1`.
If `wa1` is not to be changed, it is to be duplicated with [`clone()`](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/core.js#L332): `wa1.clone().concat(wa2)`:

```js
var ivWA = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('J78xP3jq+dhgwTJrXiQW9A==');
var ciphertextWA = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('amBBgezSkW1SQamv8pnaQg==');
var ivCiphertextWA = ivWA.clone().concat(ciphertextWA);
console.log(ivWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));           // J78xP3jq+dhgwTJrXiQW9A==
console.log(ciphertextWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));   // amBBgezSkW1SQamv8pnaQg==
console.log(ivCiphertextWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)); // J78xP3jq+dhgwTJrXiQW9GpgQYHs0pFtUkGpr/KZ2kI=
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```